# Drive removed while accessing, filesystem is corrupt, can it be fixed?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, data-recovery

The drive slipped off my desk and dropped out of a USB-HDD 2.5" SATA caddy while I was copying some files, and now it won't recognize properly in Windows. It does show up in Testdisk but before trying to recover things that way I want to know if there's a way to fix the filesystem as Testdisk is messy and unpredictable.

Edit: Sorry, the drive is 500gb, formatted to NTFS. OS is Win7 64bit.

I tried running CHKDSK on it, but it said

`C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk f:

The type of the file system is NTFS.

Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKDSK aborted.`

Comment: Please mention your OS and the file system on the partition (add tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover the data from the crashed (external) hard disk drive (NTFS)?](http://superuser.com/questions/66793/how-to-recover-the-data-from-the-crashed-external-hard-disk-drive-ntfs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have one of two types of errors:

1. Logical errors in the file structure, because the write process was interrupted. Indices and directories may no longer be in sync with the actual data written to the files.
2. Damaged physical sectors on the disk because the heads crashed into the platters when the disk hit the floor/desk.

For (1) any software 'fix' tool will work, like Windows `chkdsk`.

For (2), in order of thoroughness (which generally also indicates the time they will take to run), I recommend one of:

- Run [Seatools for DOS](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/) (not the Windows version; download the ISO), and choose the 'LONG Test'. This program is free.
- Run [HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html). [This program](http://hddreg.com/how-to-use-hdd-regenerator) is not free ($99 US).
- Run [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) (running the executable under Windows will extract an ISO that you can burn). Choose level 4 for through testing. This program is not free ($89 US) and is the only one that I know that can often recover data from damaged sectors; this may take a long time though. It comes with a money-back guarantee.

All three programs scan the hard disk at the physical level, and should be run from a bootable CD.

Strictly speaking you should try the repairs in order (2) then (1) because the software mentioned for (2) could recover actual data that is necessary for (1).

You may of course decide to do only (1), maybe that fixes enough for your purpose - but note that changes made by (1) are (also) irreversible, so (2) will not turn up more data after that, it will just fix any bad sectors.

Comment: Please see my edit and advise what to do?

Comment: Start with any of the options for (2). Then try chkdsk again. Then, if that won't work, Google for any other programs that will let uou repair your logical disk sector. In that scenario, searching for "Unable to determine volume version and state. CHKDSK aborted." may get you started.

Comment: I've got the ISOs ready, but I wondered if you think it would make a difference to run these programs with the drive in a USB caddy, or directly plugged into the SATA port on my laptop?

Comment: Better put it directly into the SATA port, the recovery sometimes can do more when the signals don't have to travel over USB.

Comment: Just a quick followup. So I'm currently running HDD regenerator and it's taken a day to reach 4% and has so far found and repaired about 11000 bad sectors (out of approx 40 million sectors completed). What are the chances of me actually getting anything back once it's all done? Also if I halt it and switch it over to a different machine and run it again will it have to go through these 11000 bad sectors again? Its taking up my main machine right now.

Comment: Maybe HDD Regen will go through those sectors again, but then probably faster. Note that you cannot estimate how much time the entire process is going to take because the bad sectors take time; the good one hardly. I know of cases where SpinRite took weeks. And how much will be salvaged is also unpredictable.