# SuperGrubDisk cannot boot up Ubuntu, can only boot up Vista, is that supposed to be the case?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, supergrubdisk

I have a Vista and 2 Ubuntu partitions and can boot to all 3.  But on Vista I deleted an Ubuntu partition and the computer cannot boot to anything.

So I burned a SuperGrubDisk, and it could let me boot to Vista, but the other choices "other OS" cannot boot up.  Is that the case?  I thought it could boot to the other Ubuntu that wasn't deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be able to simply recover the partition table, as in this answer to another Q:
[Can't read External Hard Drive anymore!](https://superuser.com/questions/8881/cant-read-external-hard-drive-anymore/8901#8901)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe SuperGrubDisk is supposed to boot up Ubuntu as well.  But none can be booted up because either due to SuperGrubDisk, Win 7 installation disc, or Vista's Disk Management tool, my other Linux partition was deleted too.

I guess that's why the note always says: always back up your data (while in reality, maybe 3% of the people have a back up device and also have the time and energy to back up 320GB of data?)